# Is there a better way I can measure the total time it takes to return data from an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking at a method like this:

```
function aa() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: href + params.param,
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .done(function (responseText) {
        xx();
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        yy();
    })
    .always(function () {
        zz(start);
    });
};

function zz(start) {
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var elapsed = end.getMilliseconds() - start.getMilliseconds();
}
```

First of all. Is this a valid way to measure the time it takes?  Also is there another way that I could do this. For example is there some way I could read something from the Ajax header and if so how could I read it?

Please note I am looking for a solution in code so I can report the times on an HTML page.

Comment: What time are you calculating? just packet transfer time or related jQuery processing time also? what is the precision you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely a valid way to measure the amount of time between when a request is issued and when data is returned.  The goal is to measure the amount of time the client sees pass between issuing a request and receiving a response, so using the client's clock is ideal.  (You usually want to avoid time comparisons that involve syncing the server's and client's clocks; using the `Date:` HTTP header would do just that.)

There are two things I would do to improve:

- Bind the `always` handler first.  Since `Deferred` callbacks are executed in the order they are added, binding `always` first means we won't have the measurement thrown off by computationally expensive operations in the `done` handler.
- There's no need to instatiate `Date` objects.  The static `Date.now()` returns the current time in ms as a Number.

You could even do the elapsed calculation in scope so it's available to your `done`/`fail` callbacks.

```
function aa() {
    var start = Date.now(), elapsed;
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: href + params.param,
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .always(function () {
        elapsed = Date.now() - start;
    });
    .done(function (responseText) {
        xx(elapsed);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        yy(elapsed);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your very good advice. You helped me with two or three different things at once. I will implement all your good suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Firebug for Firefox will tell you how long a call takes

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a solution in code that I can use to report response times to an admin that is using the page.

Comment: Tell the admin to use firebug.

Comment: Start a time at the start of the Ajax call and store the time in a var in the function then use the success to calc the time elapsed so you should be able to do it all within the 1 function. use "success" : function(data){ start - end } or whatever

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for a solution that will report it as part of the information section of a HTML page.

Comment: @Alex - Thanks but your suggestion is  just the same as I have in my question. I am trying to verify if this is a correct way to do this and also wondering if there is a way I can get information from the return headers.

Comment: you can try the getAllResponseHeaders() method to get the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that your way is pretty clean. There is nothing built-in to the response that tells you how long a request takes unless you put it there yourself. If you try to do some sort of server-side logging though, that will not take into account the time taken for the request to get across the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps run some kind of monitoring PC that just reloads the page every once in a while and keeps its own log ... sending out an alert if the transfer takes too long.

Under *nix, you could automate that with a simple script and wget and/or curl.

Comment: Hello Jeremy - I was looking for a solution that gives my admins the response times when they run a report. It's not really something I need to automate and log. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby or .Net, you can take a look to [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler). It will do what you want. Or maybe you can take check how he is doing it inside.